# How to replicate specific sound effect

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, audacity, glitch

so I would like to know how to replicate this specific sound effect that plays in this video. I would like to note that I am attempting to use Audacity to replicate said sound effect. The sound effect begins at 15:29

Comment: Which sound effect? The video is 15 minutes long. In the first 10 seconds I heard at least five. Also… what have you tried so far? What has your research shown you? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have attempted to import several raw data and attempted a paulstretch to see if I can somehow replicate that same sound, but I really could not.

Comment: this sounds like a simple varispeed stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Speed up the audio in the recording

It sounds like an explosion or like a kick/snare

Find a snare and lower the speed with e.g. audacity->effects->pitch and tempo->change tempo while having high quality enabled

Lower it again (since the maximum is not enough)

Now add some EQ to it and remove the higher and mid tones

Add some guitar filter to it and voila

here is an example